# HTML/PHP Sysmbol/Charsat only Display ??? instead of the real one

Tags: php, html

I just write some PHP code to retrieve the data from database, the data from Nickname have a symbol and some unique char. When I want to display it on browser, some of the data display ??? text instead the real text. I already add some charset but its looks nothing works. For your information i use this code to display in my Wordpress.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

$dbhost = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};./SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=DB_Tank';
$dbuser = "sa";
$dbpass = "123";

$connection = odbc_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$query = "SELECT TOP 10 NickName,FightPower FROM Sys_Users_Detail WHERE IsExist = 'True' ORDER by FightPower DESC";

echo '<table align="center" ><tr>';

$rank = odbc_exec($connection, $query);

$i = 1;
while($db = odbc_fetch_array($rank))
{
    echo '<td width="50" align="left">'.$i.'</td>';
    echo '<td width="300" align="left">'.$db['NickName'].'</td>';
    echo '<td width="150" align="left">'.$db['FightPower'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

See some of the output :
[??? Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVH7T.png)

Nickname from database :
[Real One from Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIQVk.png)

Comment: First `header()` should be sent before ANY output, that includes html, blank space, ......Second, what is the encoding that your table uses? ISO-8859-1 is quite limited compared to unicodes.

Answer (score 0):

php code save utf8 format.

Remove header.

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'); ?>
```

Right:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Try this ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');

Comment: The result still same.

Comment: sorry, I dont know. What i know is the NickName data type is nvarchar(50) and the collection of the database is Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Please try this $nick = iconv("CP850", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $db['NickName']);

Comment: Or , try this,  echo iconv('UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8',  $db['NickName']);

Comment: I try a lot, but seems the problem still same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while($db = odbc_fetch_array($rank))
{
    $string = $db['NickName'];
    if (mb_detect_encoding($string, 'utf-8', true) === false){
        $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1');
    }
    echo '<td width="50" align="left">'.$i.'</td>';
    echo '<td width="300" align="left">'.$string.'</td>';
    echo '<td width="150" align="left">'.$db['FightPower'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}
```